# How to call a function to repeat and re-prompt the user (rounds in a game)

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble figuring out why my code will not repeat itself. It works once, but then does not prompt the user again. I am trying to make a rock-paper-scissors game (no front end, just pure JS) that continues until either the user or computer earns 5 points.

I tried putting an endGame function that terminates the game but I can't play more than one round.

repl.it - https://repl.it/@heathramz/rock-paper-scissor-playground

```js
let playerSelection = prompt('Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors')

let computerScore = 0;
let userScore = 0;
let computerSelection = computerPlay()

function computerPlay() {
    let options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    let randomPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    return options[randomPlay]
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
        let result = "Tie! Try Again!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Paper beats rock!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Rock beats scissors!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;

    } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
        let result = "Tie! Try Again!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Paper beats rock!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Scissors beats paper!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;

    } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
        let result = "Tie! Try Again!";
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Rock beats scissors!";
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Scissors beats paper!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }

    if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
        endGame();
    }
}


function endGame() {
    if (userScore > computerScore) {
        console.log("Game Over! You Win! :)");
    } else if (computerScore > userScore) {
        console.log("Game Over! You Lost! :(");
    }
}

function game() {

    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    endGame();
}


game();
```

I am a newbie with JS so any corrective feedback is helpful, with any part of the code.

Comment: You are only calling playRound() once.

Comment: your main code prints a log entry, then calls `playRound`, then calls `endGame`. The `playRound` function, in turn, _just returns some string data on a valid move_, so why would you expect it to run more than once?

Comment: I think calling `playRound()` in a loop would be the easiest way to do it. As it stands right now you only call it once (outside console.log)

Comment: Also your endGame() method doesn't actually end the game. Consider returning null or something after your call in the if that will get you out of the playRound() method

Comment: Also where does the user actually choose what they want? I don't see a Scanner

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am very much a beginner at this. The challenge I am working on only has me playing the game and sending output to the console... Later I will create a UI for user choice. Right now I am just using prompt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the prompt for playerSelection and the call to computerSelection at the beginning of the play round function instead of keeping them as parameters because we're gonna need that input at the beginning of each round. It's easier to keep it in the function.

```
function playRound() {
    let playerSelection = prompt('Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors').toLowerCase();
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

Then I reduced three of your if conditions in that function to just one. You don't need to treat rock vs rock, paper vs paper, and scissors vs scissors differently because they all result in the same tie. You can just check:

```
if(playerSelection ==  computerSelection){//blah blah blah
```

once and be done with it. Then, I just updated your game function to call itself if neither player has reached 5 yet, or call endGame otherwise:

```
function game() {
    console.log(playRound());
    if(userScore < 5 && computerScore < 5){
        game();
    }
    else{
        endGame();
    }
}
```

I also took your endGame call out of the playRound function. playRound always returned a string before even reaching the endGame function, so it was pointless to have anything there. Here's all of the code together:

```js
let computerScore = 0;
let userScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
    let options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    let randomPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    return options[randomPlay]
}

function playRound() {
 let playerSelection = prompt('Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors').toLowerCase();
 let computerSelection = computerPlay();
 
    if (playerSelection ==  computerSelection) {
        let result = "Tie! Try Again!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Paper beats rock!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Rock beats scissors!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;

    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Paper beats rock!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Scissors beats paper!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;

    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
        computerScore++;
        let result = "You Lose! Rock beats scissors!";
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }
    
    if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
        userScore++;
        let result = "You Win! Scissors beats paper!"
        result += '\n'
        result += " Your Score: " + userScore
        result += '\n'
        result += " Computer Score: " + computerScore
        return result;
    }
}


function endGame() {
    if (userScore > computerScore) {
        console.log("Game Over! You Win! :)");
    } else if (computerScore > userScore) {
        console.log("Game Over! You Lost! :(");
    }
}

function game() {
    console.log(playRound());
    if(userScore < 5 && computerScore < 5){
     game();
    }
    else{
     endGame();
    }
}


game();
```

I let most of your code alone so you'd still understand everything that's going on. If you have any questions, leave a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Coming back to this and reading your explanations made it pretty clear and simple. I know I am struggling with something that so many experienced programmers must see as infantile. I appreciate you taking time to explain and assist me.

Comment: Everyone starts at the beginning! I'm glad to help. If this answer is the solution you're looking for, would you mind giving it an upvote and marking it as accepted so others will know it is the correct answer? It also gives me some points as a reward.

Answer (score 1):

Game function should not be responsible for ending the game. It simply kicks off the game loop. Also you are logging the playRound function after calling it, then calling it immediately after. This results in calling play round twice, when I believe you mean to do it once.

```
function game() {
   console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
   playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
}
```

Most games of this sort will use [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) to call the game function until end conditions are met. The other common way to do it would be with a while loop. A for loop would also work if you had a limited and discrete number of rounds.

```
if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
    endGame();
} else {
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
}
```

There is another issue that I believe you will encounter once resolving the 'single round' issue. Reading your code, I am guessing that the computer will guess the same choice every time. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I removed the extra playRound function. I will try your example and see if they helps the endGame. Also, you are right, the computer chooses a random play but then repeats that three times...

Comment: Yeah you're on the right track with that. Think about where in the control flow `computerPlay()` is called, and compare that to when you think it should logically be called in the flow of the game (probably at the start of each round...).

Comment: I used your if...else statement to create a checking function and placed it inside the for loop. Also,someone on another forum helped me figure out how to use const in the game function to get the computer to choose different options.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the for loop to stop producing prompts once it reaches game over (endGame)? (see repl.it)

Comment: My answer should handle everything that's still wrong with this code.